# single google analytics tracking Id but multiple Google Tag manager containers ids

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a single google analytics tracking Id but I have multiple Google Tag manager containers. How can I filter page views in Google Analytics based on different Google tag manager Container Ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom dimension (hit level in GA Property) with different value (i.e. the id of the GTM container that sends the hit, GTM-XXXXX).

Then in Analytics you can distinguish pageviews by adding the custom dimension as secondary dimension, so you can find the pages sent by GTM-XXXX, those from GTM-YYYYY, etc ...